# Linux Mint: How to download the latest version of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, linux-mint

Linux Mint 18.1 (64 bit).

I install Emacs by Software Manager.

It download Emacs version **24.5**. But the latest version is **25.1**.

How I can download the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to the emacs mirror page and download it directly.

http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/emacs/

Scroll down to the bottom for the latest. Unzip it into your .bin directory and add it to your path. Might want to uninstall your current emacs first so you don't have a path conflict.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to download [Portacle](https://github.com/Shinmera/portacle): it is a portable and multiplatform Emacs25, slightly customized, that ships with Git and… Common Lisp related stuff. If you ignore that you still can use this Emacs as usual, install packages and all. It doesn't come with xwidgets either. I don't know of a non-specific version of Portacle but I think it would be a great thing to have.